# Help identify model of my Orbea

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I bought the bike second hand. It has an aluminium frame and carbon forks. It has all the Orbea decals but nothing with the model name. Hoping someone recognizes it.

[image: front view]

Comment: Welcome to the website! Have you asked the seller about the model? If anyone, he/she should know it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I did ask and he didn’t know the model as well. I’m the 3rd owner of the bike.

Comment: can you post a picture of the serial number? you can probably find it below the bottom bracket, under the pedals or on the inside of the frame in between the rear wheel.
Generally it is stamped on the frame, but sometimes it is a label or some kind of plaque.

Comment: Found similar model - Vitesse

Comment: What fork does it have if possible

Answer (score 2):

I found it on the following site. Looks like it is a 1998 model but no model name mentioned.
https://buycycle.com/it-pl/bike/vintage-52327

Comment: Great find - I notice the example has a different fork as well as stem/bars/saddle, but the chainrings and wheels look the same.

Comment: I think the crank looks like a de-stickered Shimano 105 5500. That group was actually introduced in 1998, so this is plausible. [Here's the black version](https://www.shimano.com/en/100th/history/products/result.php?id=30#gallery-4) of that group, for reference.